# C/C++ Allegro program wont run

Tags: c++, c, allegro

wont load my picture
my default error message which is"error loading picture.bmp" pops up every time and wont run

```
#include "allegro.h"

int main(void)
{
    char*filename="picture.bmp";
    BITMAP*image;
    int ret;

    allegro_init();
    install_keyboard();

    set_color_depth(32);
    ret=set_gfx_mode(GFX_AUTODETECT_WINDOWED,640,480,0,0);
    if(ret!=0)
    {
              allegro_message(allegro_error);
              return 1;
              }


    image=load_bitmap(filename,NULL);
    if(!image)
    {
            allegro_message("error loading %s",filename); 
            return 1;
              }

    blit(image,screen,0,0,0,0,SCREEN_W,SCREEN_H);

    destroy_bitmap(image);

    textprintf_ex(screen,font,0,0,1,-1,"%dx%d",SCREEN_W,SCREEN_H);

    while(!keypressed());

    allegro_exit();
    return 0;

}
END_OF_MAIN()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to provide some more information...

- What platform are you using? (MS Visual C++? Linux? Mac?...)
- Which version of Allegro? (I'm guessing 4.x)

---

Assuming your question is, "How do I get my Allegro program to display my bitmap as intended," try to

**Make sure the resulting executable file and picture.bmp are in the same directory.** My guess is you are using some type of Microsoft IDE on Windows and you are trying to run the program from within the IDE (like via the debug menu or pressing F5) The resulting executable is put in a special output directory. It can't find your picture.bmp file.

**Alternatively, you can try providing the full path to your picture.bmp file.** You should only use this method to see if this is indeed the problem, though.

Comment: Note that any good IDE will let you set the path in which your program executes. So if the full path to your image works (as suggested), then just find out how to set up your IDE to start your program in the path you are expecting, and then you can go back to using relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your program might not be able to locate the bitmap image you are attempting to load. Try inserting the exact path to your bitmap in your code.

For example:

```
char*filename="C:\My Documents\Pictures\picture.bmp";
```

Comment: The back slashes must be escaped or changed to forward slashes; as is, that's an invalid filename. Also, @Leftium's answer already suggested this.